# Getting COMException when accessing Emails on Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, email, comexception

Hello I am trying to access my emails in Outlook 2010 via a C# Console Application.

Visual Studio is started with admin rights and I have added a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook v14.0.0.0` and used it as Outlook.

My Code:

```
Console.Write("starting");
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
Console.WriteLine(((Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[0]).Subject);
Console.WriteLine("readline:");
Console.ReadLine();
```

The second line, throws an error message:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

Do you know any solutions?

Comment: Try to read the following: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870655

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Should I reboot after I have changed the registry key?

Comment: I can create now a new Outlook Application, if a Outlook Instance isn't running. I started Visual Studio without admin rights.

Comment: Yes I can create a Outlook instance now, maybe it was the registry key which affected the exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to read the following: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870655

> Cause:
>   If many COM+ applications run under different user accounts
>   that are specified in the This User property, the computer cannot
>   allocate memory to create a new desktop heap for the new user.
>   Therefore, the process cannot start.
>
> WORKAROUND:
>   To work around this problem, modify the value of the
>   following registry subkey:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
>   Manager\SubSystems\Windows

Comment: Very helpful answer. Could you add the relevant change to the registry key in case the link breaks?

Comment: I had a related situation. I confirm that running visual studio (or the app) AND outlook with the same permission model (both admin or both normal) fixes this problem. However I have not tested the workaround in the registry. (Tested with Outlook 2016)

Comment: The article says to add 512 but my has set 768: `ObjectDirectory=\Windows SharedSection=1024,20480,768`.  And I have noticed that the ServerDll is set as sxssrv: `ServerDll=sxssrv`. I presume that is the default configuration in registry since I did not change it. I am wondering what is 512 anyway?

Answer (score 7):

It is because of privileges of the process.Please run Visual studio  and   outlook as administrator.

Simple solution. Run both as administrator or run both as normal privilege level.

Regards
Rameez Ali

Comment: This is way better than monkeying with the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Following Steps may be helpful...

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SubSystems - Windows

%SystemRoot%\system32\csrss.exe ObjectDirectory=\Windows SharedSection=1024,3072,512 Windows=On SubSystemType=Windows ServerDll=basesrv,1 ServerDll=winsrv:UserServerDllInitialization,3 ServerDll=winsrv:ConServerDllInitialization,2 ProfileControl=Off MaxRequestThreads=16

ASP.net user must be excist on Admin Tools/Computer Management/User

---

For 32-bit (x86), create this folder:
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop--> add Network Services

### Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files give write permissions.

in Web.config 
change impersonate= true,

in IIS for windows server 2003 select the account as NETWORK SERVICE.

In DCOMCONFIG change identity as The interactive User.

Also for the particular directory give all the rights.

---

Internet Options - Advanced tab.  Scroll all the way to the bottom and uncheck item called "Check for Publisher's certificate revocation."

Registry:
CLSID: {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
Under this key in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\, add a string value AppID = same value as the IDs Eg:{0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

Then under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\ add a string value: RunAs = Interactive User

Right click on CLSID & APPID, Permission, Security, and edit both the launch & access permissions to add and give Network Service and Interactive full permissions.

---

Disable all other Outlook add-ins: Outlook Tools menu | Options | Other tab | Advanced Options | COM Add-Ins | uncheck the items. If this solves the problem, then re-enable one add-in at a time until the problem reappears

---

give read/write access to IIS user for folder "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP"
All Dll should be placed on C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12