# Powershell, IE and Outlook

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, outlook

In single PS script, I need to:

- Operate on IE window (which means that the script needs to run elevated, as per [PowerShell IE9 ComObject has all null properties after navigating to webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869518/powershell-ie9-comobject-has-all-null-properties-after-navigating-to-webpage) [Powershell System.__ComObject.document property no longer works under IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733143/powershell-system-comobject-document-property-no-longer-works-under-ie-9))
- Then send an email using Outlook, which fails BECAUSE the PS runs elevated ([Powershell cannot create Outlook COM object from Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772500/powershell-cannot-create-outlook-com-object-from-command-prompt))

Question: how can I start Outlook un-elevated?

Current command:

> $ol = New-Object -com Outlook.Application

Comment: Temporary workaround: I'm running Outlook elevated, but that's not really the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: An alternative could be to use the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet rather than sending through Outlook as a COM object.

Comment: Send-MailMessage is the way to go if there are not issues with that method due to firewalls being in place, if you do have to deal with firewalls Powershell Runspaces are probably the way to go, you should be able to launch an elevated runspace from within a non-elevated powershell session and then use that to do the IE work, then return the data from that runspace to the main script.